# Default column value during and after adding a column

Tags: sqlite

If I specify a default when adding a non-null column to a table ...

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD COLUMN bar INT DEFAULT 42 NOT NULL
```

... does the `bar` column continue to have a default value? Or is the default only used while adding the column, to specify values in existing rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) says:

> The *column-def* rule defines the characteristics of the new column.

So the default value applies to the column, not to the operation:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(x);
sqlite> ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar INT DEFAULT 42 NOT NULL;
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo(x) VALUES(1);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
1|42
```